# Understanding log iteration of for-loop

Tags: c++

Why does the following `for`-loop compute `floor(log_2(m))`, rather than `ceil(log_2(m))` (which is what I would have expected)?

```
for (int m = <some number>; m > 1; m /= 2) //<some number> is integer >= 0
    cout << “Here\n”;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, for example, 3 / 2 is 1 when both 3 and 2 are integers, the loop will terminate without considering the fractions. So you get log_2(3) = 1.